# Where can I buy SSD merchandise?

Tags: discussion

C'mon Andrew. I would rock an SSD t-shirt at a trade show any day.

Comment: Ha! Love it :-) 

Answer (score 6):

Ooh, can we make them like baseball jerseys and get our username across the back?

Comment: put out a hockey jersey and I'm waaaaay in.

Comment: hockey, soccer, baseball, whatever.

Answer (score 4):

Gotta include the number of badges on there somewhere too.
The sleeve maybe?

Answer (score 2):

ditto man.  ditto.

Answer (score 2):

Ha ha, great idea :) @Steve, love the username suggestion too!

Answer (score 2):

if someone draw the patter, i would ask one on vectro graphics format. i'll do it my self :))
(my flatmate makes T-shirts for fun, and one of my friend doing this http://www.thedoleshirt.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Once the site graduates (leaves beta), something neat happens ...

***Stack Exchange will print this stuff and make it available to deserving users!***

We generally print:

- T-Shirts (high quality)
- Stickers (re-usable)
- A third item that fits the site topic which users would appreciate

... with the logo that our professional designers create for you after soliciting your feedback.

Sure, we could probably do Jerseys instead when the time comes, we'll see then.

As for "deserving" users? We generally send out some stuff to folks in the first two pages of users, sorted by all time reputation, the moderators and then to individuals that we've seen go 'above and beyond' in the care and promotion of the site.

I'm also known to hold impromptu, sort of 'silly' contests here on meta to give others a chance to get some. They aren't for sale, though - partly because we're just not set up to handle fulfillment at that scale, and needing to earn them somehow tends to increase their value for folks that receive them.

***If you are going to a conference or event where you have a chance to promote the site prior to that, please contact me directly (tpost@stackoverflow.com).*** I can provide you with some of our Stack Exchange branded items that you can use to give out to attendees.

Comment: This is why Tim is affectionately known as the loot pinata. ;)

Comment: Wait, that's _not_ because people keep chasing me with sticks?

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a SSD "Retro" Jersey in large. ;)